# How to declare a property out of substring of existing/in-build property in Ant?

Tags: ant

Right now I have 100+ build xml files which calls a task to get substring out of a property. I would like to have this property declared in properties file itself to avoid this overhead of calling task 100+ times to get the actual value. Any suggestions on how can we deal this better?
Just to explain in more detail:

```
file.properties
property0 = value0
property1 = value1
...

build[1...100].xml
...
...
#call ant task to extract sub string from property1 value.
...
```

===========

Is there a way to extract substring from property1 and assign to some another property2 in file.properties itself and directly refer property2 in all 100+ build.xml files? Or suggest any better way/idea. Thanks.

Comment: Not entirely certain what the problem is.... Why can't you create a single properties file and import it by each build file?

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for reply. Yes, I am using only one property file but manipulating property (extracting sub string of its value) in 100+ build.xml files. I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Sounds like you have a solution in mind that is not quite working. Perhaps you should reframe what you're trying to achieve, for example it's more normal to have a single build.xml file. Why do you have 100+ build files? And what are they doing?